# Is it acceptable to have two functions that run each endlessly?

Tags: python, function, python-2.7

I built a simple Python program to find if an input is a power of two or not. I have two functions, `power_of_two` and `play_again`. After `power_of_two` runs, `play_again` then runs and reruns `power_of_two`

Here's my code:

```
num = int(raw_input('Input a number (type 0 to quit): '))
def power_of_two(x):
    y=1
    z=[]
    while y < x:
        y=y*2
        z.append(y)
    if x in z or x == 1:
        print 'true'
    elif x == 0:
        quit()
    else: 
        print 'false'
    play_again()

def play_again():
    num = int(raw_input('Input a number: '))
    power_of_two(num)

power_of_two(num)
```

**Is code like this acceptable among Python programmers or is there a better way to replicate what I am doing here?**

Comment: This might be more appropriate for the [code review stack exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Try using OOP @michaelpri

Comment: @michaelpri You would probably get more answers and better reception there, but it's up to you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

One problem with this approach is that you will eventually run out of stack, because we have a pair of mutually recursive functions. Each call uses up memory in the stack, which is never recovered.

This isn't obvious with an interactive program since it will take a long time to create enough recursive calls, but if we speed things up:

```
def power_of_two(x):
    print(str(x))
    play_again(x)

def play_again(x):
    power_of_two(x+1)

power_of_two(1)
```

We get:

```
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object
```

Some languages can do tail-call optimisation so this technique works fine - but in Python it's better to create a loop to "play again", unless you can be sure that there will only be a small call depth.

Comment: @michaelpri That depends on if you can provide an iterable which brings the needed conditions.

Answer (score 3):

It's not a very good way to programme in general because (aside from the possible maximum recursion depth problem) if your programme gets more complicated, you will end up with multiple [spaghetti-like](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code) jumps between different functions, making it increasingly hard to read and debug.

Instead it is more standard to have a `main` function that controls the overall programme flow and calls the other functions. It will also be better to have a clearer separation of roles between the two functions.

```
def power_of_two(x):
    y = 1
    while y < x:
        y *= 2
    return y == x

def get_number():
    return int(raw_input('Input a number (type 0 to quit): '))

def main():
    while True:
        n = get_number()
        if n == 0:
            return
        print power_of_two(n)

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

No - as was already said, you have the risk to run into stack overflow.

You would better do

```
def power_of_two(x):
    y=1
    z=[]
    while y < x:
        y=y*2
        z.append(y)
    if x in z or x == 1:
        print 'true'
    elif x == 0:
        quit()
    else: 
        print 'false'


def play():
    while True:
        num = int(raw_input('Input a number (type 0 to quit): '))
        power_of_two(num)
```

This is close to your solution, but far from perfect.

It would be better to jet the function just do what it promises: check if the number is a power of two and nothing else.

```
def power_of_two(x):
    y = 1
    z = set((1,)) # as only "in" is performed, a set is better here...
    # Having 1 in the set initially saves the extra check for x == 1...
    while y < x:
        y = y * 2
        z.append(y)
    return x in z


def play():
    while True:
        num = int(raw_input('Input a number (type 0 to quit): '))
        if num == 0:
            return # or just break
        else:
            print power_of_two(num) # prints "True" or "False"
            print 'true' if power_of_two(num) else 'false' # prints "true" or "false"
```

If you want to use a for loop, you can craft an iterable in the form of a generator which yields values until there are no more:

```
def numbers():
    while True:
        num = int(raw_input('Input a number (type 0 to quit): '))
        if num == 0:
            return # or just break
        else:
            yield num

def play():
    for num in numbers():
        # power_of_two() is the same as above.
        print power_of_two(num) # prints "True" or "False"
        print 'true' if power_of_two(num) else 'false' # prints "true" or "false"
```

Even this inner while loop can be replaced with a for loop, e. g. for counting:

```
def numbers():
    import itertools
    for round in itertools.count(1):
        num = int(raw_input('Input number ' + str(round) + ' (type 0 to quit): '))
        if num == 0:
            return # or just break
        else:
            yield num
```

Comment: Why use `quit()` instead of just `break`? From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html?highlight=quit#quit) I don't quite understand when `quit()` is appropriate.

Comment: @HåkenLid You are right; I used it here only because the OP used it.